# How to update iOS by using Profile Manager as mobile device management (MDM) service?

Tags: ios, ipad, mobile-device-management, auto-update

I cannot find a way to remotely update iOS version for iPads by using Profile Manager as mobile device management (MDM) service. All devices are enrolled in Apple's DEP program.

I can choose Install Updates, select iOS 12 and press Install, but this won't install iOS 12. iPads will download iOS 12 but won't install. I need to open iPad cases and start using iPads to get the installation started. Doing this for hundreds of iPads is painful.

Comment: Hey @JPX did you find a solution to this problem? I am struggling with the same issue. Via Profile Manager I can trigger the iOS Update but it will only download the Update but not install it. Haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Hello @Cimoe . No I have not found a solution. We have charging carts with USB connection so you could use  MAC laptop to updates iPads but by default iPads won't trust that laptop. Maybe you could install trust profile via MDM.